# from yyyy-mm-dd to mm-yy?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, datetime

How do I convert a date like
2020-03-25 to 03-20 ?

I tried this:

```
select 
  FORMAT (d.[Date], 'MM-YY') as monthyear
from x  d
```

But I am getting 03-YY

Why do I not get the year?

Comment: I think it should be 'MM-yy'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server:

```
select format(d.[Date], 'MM-yy') as monthyear
from x d
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally suggest using `CONVERT` with a style code over `FORMAT`; `FORMAT` can be a pretty slow function. The style `5` with the first 3 characters removed is what you're after:

```sql
SELECT STUFF(CONVERT(YT.[date],5),1,3,'') AS MonthYear
FROM dbo.YourTable YT;
```